# Check/Uncheck - ifChecked not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, icheck

UPDATE: I'm using the following [plugin](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck)

I'm trying to check if the checkbox is checked when the user refresh the page or reload the page and here is what I have used but I have done the debugging and it never execute the `second IF` condition

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    if ($("input#CreatePart").is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked');
    }
});

$('input').on('ifUnchecked', function (event) {
    if ($("input#CreatePart").is(':checked')) {
        alert('un-checked');
    }
});

<input checked="checked" class="icheck" data-val="true" 
  data-val-required="The Create new Part field is required." 
  id="CreatePart" name="CreatePart" type="checkbox" value="true" 
/>
<input name="CreatePart" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

Comment: you realize that you checkbox values are lost on page refresh?

Comment: no i did not realized that; that might be my issue? but the plugin i'm using when I refresh my page and I see that checkbox is checked

Comment: is that your default state of the button?

Comment: no its not default, the user check or unchecked

Comment: your page can't save the state of a user checkbox your page may be cached by the browser that is why you see them as saved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

on page load:

```
 alert($('input').is(':checked'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ypwjvt4/18/

else use:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-orange',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-orange',
        increaseArea: '20%' // optional
    });

    $('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
      alert('Checked');
    });

    $('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
      alert('unchecked');
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ypwjvt4/17/

Comment: first code snippet does not work obviously and the second code please read my question again and let me know if you do not understand.

Comment: when i checked and refresh then i am getting `alert true` but when i unchecked and refresh the page i am still getting `alert=true` and checkbox is checked....

Comment: you page doesn't save the state of a checkbox you need to save the state of the checkbox in a db or localstorage/cookie

Answer (score 0):

Use on **change** event instead on using ifChecked or ifUnchecked

```
$('input.icheck').on('change', function (event) {
    if ($("input#CreatePart").is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked');
    }else{
       alert("unchecked");
    }

});
```

Comment: @AbuHamzah is there any error in console and also use $('input.icheck') and see if it works as there are two input field

Comment: i'm not getting any error but its not exeucting the `if ` condition which is `if ($("input#CreatePart")` nor its going to the else condtion

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition on ifUnchecked to make sure the checkbox is NOT checked instead of checked.

You were checking to see if the box is checked when the unchecked event is fired which that would never happen.

```
$('input').on('ifUnchecked', function (event) {
    if ($("input#CreatePart").not(':checked')) {
        alert('un-checked');
    }
});
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ejLbgt7b/

Answer (score 0):

In my case the 'ifChecked' event also didn't trigger but then I noticed that I was initializing iCheck twice in different places of my code.

```
$('input').iCheck();
// and later in the code:
$('input').iCheck();
```

Removing the redundant initialization helped and 'ifChecked' started to work.