# checkbox does not change visual state

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

This might be very simple, but I am breaking my head for an hour already.
I have a simple radio with two buttons:

```
<input class="form-control icheck" id="cash_prize" name="cash_prize" type="radio" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<input class="form-control icheck" id="noncash_prize" name="cash_prize" type="radio" value="0" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
```

And a checkbox:

```
<input class="form-control icheck" id="issuable_via_logistics" name="issuable_via_logistics" type="checkbox" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
```

On radio with id "cash_prize" On click I fire up a JS function:

```
$('#cash_prize').on('ifChecked', function(){
    var chkbox = $('#issuable_via_logistics');
    chkbox.prop('checked', false);
```

Checkbox gets unchecked if I am checking it's state, but visually it remains checked. Please, how to change that?

Comment: There is no standard `ifChecked` event (you'd use `change` for a checkbox). Is that event provided by some library you're using?

Comment: why is the checkbox `opacity:0`? Could you turn this into a snippet please? Also, checkout this question, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery & here's another link you might find helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900838/check-uncheck-ifchecked-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$(element).iCheck('uncheck')`

so in your case:

```
$('#issuable_via_logistics').iCheck('uncheck')
```

Comment: Love you! Yes, that's what you get when you use libraries you are not familiar with.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. @Zhong Wang

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. It's what I've used to change the state of check boxes in the past, and is also what [this answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5916151/10296901) says should be good.

```
$('#cash_prize').on('ifChecked', function(){
    $('#issuable_via_logistics')[0].checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
<html>
<body>
cash prize: 
<input class="form-control icheck" id="cash_prize" name="cash_prize" type="radio">
<br />
non cashprize: 
<input class="form-control icheck" id="noncash_prize" name="cash_prize" type="radio">
<br />
<br />
checkbox: 
<input class="form-control icheck" id="issuable_via_logistics" name="issuable_via_logistics" type="checkbox" >

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cash_prize').change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $('#issuable_via_logistics').prop('checked', true);
            };
        });

        $('#noncash_prize').change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $('#issuable_via_logistics').prop('checked', false);
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might hep you.

```js
$('#cash_prize').change(function(){
 if ($(this).prop('checked'), true){
  $('#issuable_via_logistics').prop('checked',false);
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="cash_prize" name="cash_prize" type="radio" value="1">Prize 1
<input id="noncash_prize" name="cash_prize" type="radio" value="0" >Prize 2

<input id="issuable_via_logistics" name="issuable_via_logistics" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
```